# web3j.ethSendRawTransaction wait until the transaction is successfully mined - Web3j

Tags: web3j, ethereumj

Im trying to send 0 ether to the same account with Web3j, however when i run this code it give me directly the transaction hash, even if the transaction has not been mined yet and still pending. I can't use the method Transfer.sendFund(..) because i need the nonce to be given by me.

```
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, 
    gasPriceInWei, gasLimit, credentials.getAddress(), BigInteger.ZERO);

byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, 
    credentials);

String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);

EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction =
    web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).sendAsync().get();

String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();

System.out.println("transaction hash: " , transactionHash )
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this probelm?

("web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).send()" dont solve this)

(watch all new transactions in each new blocks until my transaction occure is a solution, but is there a better way)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
while (true) {
    EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = web3j
        .ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)
        .send();
     if (transactionReceipt.getResult() != null) {
         break;
     }
     Thread.sleep(15000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Web3j have two implementations of `org.web3j.tx.response.TransactionReceiptProcessor`: `PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor` and `QueuingTransactionReceiptProcessor`

Example:

```
TransactionReceiptProcessor receiptProcessor = new PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor(
        web3,
        TransactionManager.DEFAULT_POLLING_FREQUENCY,
        TransactionManager.DEFAULT_POLLING_ATTEMPTS_PER_TX_HASH);

TransactionReceipt receipt = receiptProcessor
        .waitForTransactionReceipt(sendTransaction.getTransactionHash());
```